# How to redirect all traffic to Apache document root

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have tinycms application and how could I forward all traffic to document root?

Example:

```
http://<IP-address>/ADFADSF/adsfadsf --> /
http://domain.com/adsf --> /
```

Currently, I have this in my .htaccess

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule admin/$ index.php?view=admin [QSA]
Options -Indexes
```

Thanks.
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^/?.+$ / [L,R]
```

Using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch ^/.+ /
```

This will,m of course, render the `RewriteRule admin/$ index.php?view=admin [QSA]` rule useless, or at the very least, cause some conflicts. So you should either comment that rule out, or create a special exception where all traffic except `admin/` gets redirected.

---

EDIT:

> How Im gonna do that to make an rule except admin/ ?

Here's one way to do it, I'm only guessing that this is the behavior you want. This stuff does not change, it's fine the way it is:

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
```

Add a:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Then:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|admin)
RewriteRule ^/?.+$ / [L,R]

RewriteRule admin/$ index.php?view=admin [QSA,L]
```

So putting all that together, you have the **deny** for accessing *.htaccess* files. Then you have your `Options`, then your rewrite rules. You need to turn the RewriteEngine on, then **redirect** any request that isn't `/index.php` or `/admin`, then *internally rewrite* `/admin` to `/index.php`.

Comment: Thanks Jon, How Im gonna do that to make an rule except admin/ ?

Comment: The RewriteRule you've stated above is working fine. However, when I type any subdirectory, the page will display the web root index.php but the image is missing and display is so ugly. I am not sure what's causing this.

Comment: Hi John, I tried the rules you've stated above and the only problem is that the page is lossing images and designs.

Comment: @JamesWise It's a relative vs absoluate URL issue, not a rewrite one. Your images, css, whatever, are linked via relative URLs, you either need to set a valid `<base href="/whatever/">` or change all your links to absolute ones

Comment: even I try http://<IP-address>/logo.png or jpg, it doesn't show up and instead it redirects to web root index page. The logo image are located in the main web root directory. Maybe there's something to add or change in Rewrite rule code you've provided? Thanks

Comment: @JamesWise Oh, of course not, you said you wanted to **"forward all traffic to document root"**. A request for an image or script or style is *"traffic*", therefore, it'll get redirected to the document root, and not the image/script/style/whatever.

Comment: @JamesWise in light of this new valuable information you want to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` right before the condition to exclude `^/(index\.php|admin)`

Comment: it's working! Could you advise any recommended links to learn this rewrite stuff? Thanks Jon! :)